# How to use lerna.js with travis ci?

Tags: travis-ci, lerna

I'm using [lerna.js](https://lernajs.io) and I struggle to find proper documentation on setting up a monorepo with [Travis](https://travis-ci.org). I only found this [repo](https://github.com/jkusa/lerna-travis) and this [blog post](https://lord.io/blog/2014/travis-multiple-subdirs/), but they're both minimal and suboptimal.

How could I accomplish all of the following?

1. Run tests and linters across all packages
2. Cache `node_modules` in every package
3. Preferably, declare a different `.travis.yml` file for every package

I managed to do point 1 by doing:

```
env:
  matrix:
    - PACKAGE=contracts

matrix:
  include:
  - stage: tests
    name: "unit tests"
    script:
      - cd packages/contracts
      - npm install && npm run test
  - stage: tests
    name: "unit tests with coverage"
    script:
      - cd packages/contracts
      - npm install && npm run test
    env: SOLIDITY_COVERAGE=true
  - stage: tests
    name: "static tests"
    script:
      - cd packages/contracts
      - npm install && npm run lint
```

However, builds are very slow, as `node_modules` doesn't get cached. Similarly, it's a rather verbose process to declare all the tests in top-down fashion, I'd much rather prefer bottom-up via individual `.travis.yml` files.

Answer (score -1):

A rather hackish way, but here's how [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) solved this problem:

```
install:
  - npm install -g lerna
  - npm install -g yarn
  - npm run bootstrap

script:
  - npm run ci
```

Lo and behold the usage of this [ci](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/develop/scripts/ci.sh) script. Essentially, they deferred the complexity of dealing with multiple subpackages to a bash script, which is nice, but a bit disingenuous to Travis.

I ended up switching to CircleCI as their syntax is somehow more intuitive and easy-to-use.